# Web scrapping: How do I download the images that appear on mouseover from a page that do not have the img tag?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, splinter

While web scrapping I'm trying to download the images that appear on a page on the mouseover action. You can see below how 2 pictures are identified in the code. How can I download them?

I'm using Splinter, but could use Selenium or another python library.

Thank you in advance

```
<div id="item712" class="genre scanme ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" scan="true" style="color: rgb(58, 56, 28); top: 297.377px; left: 566.691px; z-index: 29;" onmouseover="playx(&quot;img311.jpg&quot;, &quot;712&quot;, &quot;1.18*Pain + 1.09*Disappointment + 0.96*Sadness&quot;, this);" onmouseout="unplayx(&quot;img311.jpg&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, this);" title="712">M<br></div>

<div id="item713" class="genre scanme ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" scan="true" style="color: #D1D197; top: 387.1925px; left: 717.9348px;" onmouseover="playx(&quot;img312.jpg&quot;, &quot;713&quot;, &quot;3.93*Pain + 2.70*Sadness&quot;, this);" onmouseout="unplayx(&quot;img312.jpg&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, this);" title="713">M<br></div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: cna you share the url?